# Make match input and if-else

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have my script here

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import commands

db=''

def launch():
        # Database Check.
            if db.lower() == 'y':
                commands.db_download()
            else:
                db.lower() == 'n'



root = Tk()


checklabel = Label(root, text="Check for new databases? Y/N: ")
checkentree = Entry(root, textvariable=db)
checkbutton = Button(root, text="Go", command=launch)


checklabel.pack()
checkentree.pack()
checkbutton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

And everything works except the matching part. 
When I enter "y" or "n", or even anything else in the Entry box and click Go, nothing happens... Why isnt anything happening? And how could i make it work?

Comment: Have you tried to use `print()` to troubleshoot? I can tell you for sure that you are not using `textvariable` correctly.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but maybe your interface would be simpler if you just had a single button labeled "check for new databases". Why make your user type a letter _and_ press a button when they could do just one?

Comment: @Kevin Because i didn't even knew it was possible. I mean i wanted it to match my launch function so I didnt knew I could do it in one single button. I'm intrigued now, how could i achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You already know that you can bind a function to a button, because you're binding `launch` already. To make the button call db_download directly, you just need to change the line to  `checkbutton = Button(root, text="Check for new databases", command=commands.db_download)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkentree = Entry(root, textvariable=db)
```

The `textvariable` parameter should be a StringVar. But `db` is a string, not a StringVar.
Try passing a StringVar instead.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import commands

def launch():
        # Database Check.
            if db.get().lower() == 'y':
                commands.db_download()
            #don't actually need these following lines because they don't do anything
            #else:
            #    #db.get().lower() == 'n'


root = Tk()
db=StringVar()


checklabel = Label(root, text="Check for new databases? Y/N: ")
checkentree = Entry(root, textvariable=db)
checkbutton = Button(root, text="Go", command=launch)


checklabel.pack()
checkentree.pack()
checkbutton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is 1 change you need to make and a couple that are a good idea to fix.

1st the "need" to change:

When using a `textvaraible` in a tkinter widget you must use one of the ObjectVars (IE: StringVar, IntVar and so on). Keep in mind also that you will need to use `.get()` on `db` as the `get()` method is how you grab a value from an ObjectVar.

To accomplish this change this:

```
db = ''

def launch():
    if db.lower() == 'y':
```

To this:

```
db = tk.StringVar()
db.set('') # not actually required in this instance but still good to know how to set the value of a ObjectVar.

def launch():
    if db.get().lower() == 'y':
```

As well as move your `db` tkinter code past the `root` or else the StringVar will throw this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'` as you have not yet started the tk instance for the StringVar to latch onto.

That said you should also change how you import tkinter and maybe clean up your widget names and how you pack.

It is better to do `import tkinter as tk` over `from tkinter import *` because this helps prevent accidentally overwriting an import form other imports or your own variable/functions/class names. To work with this new import method you just need to use the prefix `tk.` for each method/widget use.

If you are not going to modify a widget down the road (IE: a permanent label, button or so on) you do not need to assign it to a variable and can simply use your geometry manager (in this case `pack()`) on the widget directly.

Lastly your `if/else` statement is not exactly correct. It will function but this line `db.lower() == 'n'` is not doing what you think it is doing. An `else` statement does not have any conditions to meet. It just is the last option in an `if/elif/else` statement that will run if none of the other conditions are met. That said if you have nothing you want to be done if none of the other conditions are met you can simple delete the `else` portion of your logic statement.

Take a look at the below code:

```
import tkinter as tk


def launch():
if db.get().lower() == 'y':
    print('commands.db_download()')
else:
    print('not y')   


root = tk.Tk()
db = tk.StringVar()
db.set('')

tk.Label(root, text="Check for new databases? Y/N: ").pack()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=db).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Go", command=launch).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "As well as move your db and launch function inside the tkinter code past the root". I agree that it is important to create `db` only after creating `root`. But I think it's fine to leave the `launch` definition at the top of the file. Generally speaking, it's syntactically valid for a function to use a variable name even if that variable doesn't exist when the function is defined.

Comment: @Kevin ya you are probably right. Its probably just because my habit of doing everything in a class so all my functions/methods are inside the class after tk has been initiated.

Comment: Really thank you so much you and @Kevin for your help! Your both answers worked 100% fine!